# Finding the image of the unit disk under the complex function $f_\alpha(z)=\frac{z}{1+\alpha z^2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Define for $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ the function 
$$f_\alpha(z)=\frac{z}{1+\alpha z^2}.$$

One can prove that $f_\alpha$ is injective when restricted to the unit disk and when $|\alpha|\leq 1$. What is the image of the unit disk $U$ when $\alpha\leq 1$?

By Theorem 14.14 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, we have that $f(U)$ contains all complex numbers whose modulus is less than 1/4. What more can be said about $f(U)$?

Comment: Suppose $\alpha = 1$ and $z = i$; what's the value of your function? Perhaps my question is really, "When you say the unit disk, do you mean the open disk or the closed one?"

Comment: I mean open unit disk @JohnHughes

Comment: by open mapping theorem $f(U)$ is open,

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Sure, but that is clear. What further information can one get?

Comment: @Adel: we don't know *what* is clear to you, because you haven't told us much about your own thoughts on the problem.

Comment: @JohnHughes Rudin's The fundamental concepts from Rudin's Real and Comlex Analysis.

Comment: Suggestion: Estimate what the image looks like for $\alpha$ nearly $0$, and for $\alpha$ nearly (or equal to) $1$; that'll at least give you a starting point for making some guesses. Note, too, that you can rewrite this as $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}} \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}z}{1 + (\sqrt{\alpha}z)^2}$, so a substitution of $\sqrt{\alpha} z$ for $z$ might make things easier to think about.

Comment: Did you forget to mention that this is Exercise 7 in Rudin's book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f_{\alpha^2}(z) = \alpha^{-1} f_1(\alpha z)$, so for each $\alpha$, $f_\alpha(U)$ is a scaled and rotated version of $f_1(|\alpha|^{1/2} U)$.

$f_1$ maps the unit circle to 
$(-\infty, -1/2] \cup [1/2, \infty) \subset \mathbb R$, and maps the circles of radius $r < 1$ to disjoint simple closed curves: here are the images under $f_1$ of the circles centred at $0$ with radius $3/4$ (red), $1/2$ (green), $1/4$ (blue).

[image]